# Running a batch file and a single command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am a beginner at batch programming and I'm wondering if it is possible to run a batch file along with just one command already executed and accept a command from the user and execute it.

For example this is what I want to happen: 
1) Run batch file 
2) Type one command and press enter. The command executes.

But I want that all to happen just by running the batch file by itself. 
This might be a very simple task to most of you but I've searched and can't get a solid solution.

Help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `yourbatch.bat & echo done.`

Comment: What are the "command"s you want to enter after the batch file starts? Are they cmd.exe shell command like `DIR` or `FIND`? Are you looking for a shortcut way to enter the command?

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p Variab=Command_here:
%Variab%
```

This will take input to `Variab` and then execute the input.